# Post-hoc analysis for Tobit model using Censreg in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, tobit-regression

I have a blood biomarker (BHB) in my dataset with censored distribution (i.e., lower detection limit of 96). I want to use Tobit regression with the Censreg package in R. My objective is to see if there are significant differences in BHB levels between 5 stages (categorical variable). As I need post-hoc pairwise comparisons I used the qdrg() function from the emmeans package. The issue I have is that I obtain NaN for all p-values.

Here is the script:

```
m <- censReg(BHB ~ as.factor(stage), left = 96, data = df)
summary(m)

coef <- coef(m)
summary(coef)


coef <- coef(m)[1:5]
vcov <- vcov(m)[1:5, 1:5]
rg <- qdrg(BHB ~ stage, data=df, coef=coef, vcov=vcov, df=m$df.residual)
emmeans(rg, pairwise ~ stage, adjust="none")
```

Here are the results:

```
$emmeans
 stage emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1-3      -288 2448 88    -5153     4577
 4-6      -288 2448 88    -5153     4577
 7-9      -288 2448 88    -5153     4577
 10-12    -288 2448 88    -5153     4577
 13-15    -288 2448 88    -5153     4577

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast          estimate SE df t.ratio p.value
 (1-3) - (4-6)            0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (1-3) - (7-9)            0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (1-3) - (10-12)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (1-3) - (13-15)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (4-6) - (7-9)            0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (4-6) - (10-12)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (4-6) - (13-15)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (7-9) - (10-12)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (7-9) - (13-15)          0  0 88     NaN     NaN
 (10-12) - (13-15)        0  0 88     NaN     NaN
```

Here is coef:

```
           (Intercept)   as.factor(stage)4-6   as.factor(stage)7-9 as.factor(stage)10-12 
             -288.2748               -58.7353               286.7880               388.6779 
as.factor(stage)13-15 
              505.4128
```

Here is vcov:

```
                       (Intercept) as.factor(stage)4-6 as.factor(stage)7-9 as.factor(stage)10-12
(Intercept)                5992615             -5989906             -5991956               -5992401
as.factor(stage)4-6      -5989906            129807896              5990016                5989942
as.factor(stage)7-9      -5991956              5990016              5992332                5991802
as.factor(stage)10-12    -5992401              5989942              5991802                5992657
as.factor(stage)13-15    -5992594              5989909              5991941                5992382
                       as.factor(stage)13-15
(Intercept)                          -5992594
as.factor(stadge)4-6                  5989909
as.factor(stage)7-9                  5991941
as.factor(stage)10-12                5992382
as.factor(stage)13-15                5992983
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There does seem to be some problem in your invocation of the function from `emmeans`, as the `emmean` values are all the same as the Intercept from the Tobit model rather than the sums of the intercept with the corresponding factor-specific coefficients. Thus the apparent contrasts among the `emmean` values, the differences among them, all end up as 0. Software-specific questions are off-topic on this site, however.

The bigger statistical problem is that your Tobit model itself doesn't seem to work very well. The standard errors of the coefficients, the square roots of the diagonal elements of the `vcov` matrix, are much larger in magnitude than the coefficients themselves, so it's not clear that your model is explaining much of the variance in the BHB biomarker values. Pull back and evaluate the model itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a lot of censored data points: 63 data points at are the detection limit (96) while 30 have higher values (and 6 are missing). Could the model not work very well because of this?

Comment: @Falco in this case, with values that presumably must be non-negative, the negative intercept suggests something even worse than not enough data. My guess is that the assumption of underlying Gaussian distributions isn't working, as you shouldn't be predicting a negative value. Maybe try a Tobit model on log-transformed BHB values, with the left-censoring cutoff similarly transformed. That way, at least, your model will be making theoretically possible predictions. Also, you should have 10-20 uncensored observations per coefficient, so consider grouping the stages even more.